# Safe key combinations for global shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Is there any combination of modifier keys that could be considered 'safe' for setting global shortcuts with a third-party app? For example, I do window snapping with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>J|L</kbd>, but <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> would conflict with Chrome's dev tools shortcut.

I'd like a set of modifiers I can use for virtually any global shortcut I want without conflict.

Comment: I use 3 & 4 key modifiers to stay out of the way of other apps.

Answer (score 1):

For personal macros, I usually simply use the control key—practically nothing uses just the control key as a modifier; it's always paired with command. (e.g. <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>J/L</kbd>)

If you're asking so you can include it in software you're developing to widely distribute, though, I wouldn't recommend this for exactly the reason that it's a good idea for personal use: it's pretty non-standard.